# Where are android-sdk executables (installed with apt)?

Tags: virtualization, android, emulation, android-sdk

I installed android-sdk via `apt`, on xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS But there's no `android` command in my path! In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576908/unable-to-launch-android-sdk-manager-in-terminal), they locate the tools for a home installation. But I navigated to `/usr/local/lib/android/tools` and it just contains the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K mars  28 20:10 bin/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,1K févr. 28  2017 package.xml
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4,0K mars  28 20:10 proguard/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   69 févr. 28  2017 source.properties
```

and in `bin/`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 mars  11  2019 e2fsck -> /sbin/e2fsck*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 mars  11  2019 fsck.ext4 -> /sbin/fsck.ext4*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 mars  11  2019 mkfs.ext4 -> /sbin/mkfs.ext4*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 mars  11  2019 resize2fs -> /sbin/resize2fs*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 mars  11  2019 screenshot2 -> ../../../../bin/screenshot2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 mars  11  2019 tune2fs -> /sbin/tune2fs*
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Is the ubuntu package completely out-of-date?

I saw ["Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle"](https://askubuntu.com/a/634085/382931) as well, but I thought installing the whole android-studio gas-machine wasn't necessary.

My **final goal** is simply to run an **android emulation**, in order to install a few apps. I also tried android-x86 within virtualbox, but for some reason some apps I needed didn't appear in the google store.

So could someone explain me first how to *install and run* the android-sdk `emulator` command, or alternatively how to set up an android virtual machine with maximum compatibility?

PS: I tried to use `ubuntu-make` as well, but neither the snap install nor the ppa install succeeded to download the android development tools.

[EDIT]

result of `dpkg -L android-sdk`:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/android-sdk
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/bin
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/android-sdk
/usr/share/doc/android-sdk/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/android-sdk/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/android-sdk/copyright
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/e2fsck
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/fsck.ext4
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/mkfs.ext4
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/resize2fs
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/screenshot2
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/tune2fs
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguard
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguardgui.jar
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/retrace.jar
```

Instead I installed from the android site, but only the [commandline tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools), and then `bin` only contains:

```
apkanalyzer  avdmanager  lint  screenshot2  sdkmanager
```

and I get some errors when issuing `sdkmanager`:

```
Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

Someone suggests Anbox, but if I understood correctly it's a different emulator. From what I grasped, it has different capabilities and most notably I believe it creates Android devices without any google app preinstalled. If I'm wrong, I'm willing to make a try.

[EDIT 2]

Concerning the above java error, I fixed it following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60731814/4614641).
Now I just need to get set up on how to install and run an emulator.

Comment: @guiverc sorry, typo fixed.

Comment: List the files in the package with `dpkg -L android-sdk`

Comment: Currently there is no package with [`android`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=android) command to support the wanted functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install and run Anbox in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033620/how-to-install-and-run-anbox-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @waltinator, Thanks for your suggestion, I provided some extra info in the answer.

Comment: @N0rbert indeed, I learned [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html) that `android` is deprecated. I'm not sure how to replace this functionality at the command line, but probably with `avdmanager` and `sdkmanager`.